# Finding the limit of function involving log and quotient

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find the limit of the function below, and what x tends to:

$$\frac{x^3-4\log x}{4x+3e^x}$$

Solution so far:

Because the function involves an exponential in the denominator and a logarithm in the numerator, the domain is $\infty$

Seeing as as $x\rightarrow \infty$ for $x^3-4\log x$ and $4x+3e^3$, we have:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^3-4\log x}{4x+3e^x} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}=0$$

I think this is right, but proving it in a succinct manner, it doesn't really do the job.

I'm also confused at the prospect of either expression tending to infinity faster than the other, which is certainly the case, but is this important?

Any suggestions/corrections?

Comment: L'Hospital rule, may be

Comment: You may use L'Hospital's rule successively and reduce the polynomial terms in numerator and denominator to constants. Now if you take limits, you will get the answer as zero. The log term converges to zero after you apply L'Hospital's rule and take limits as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Typing `$\log x$` produces $\log x$.

Answer (score 1):

Using L'Hospital's rule thrice, we get:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{6-\frac{8}{x^3}}{3e^x} = 0$$
You could also have just deduced after using L'Hospital twice that the denominator with $e^x$ will increase faster than $6x$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

L'Hopital's rule comes handy.Alternatively you can also use the power series of $e^x$.
We have $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+.......$.It is usually intuitive because $e^x$ grows at a higher rate than any polynomial and hence having $e^x$ in the denominator usually give 0 as x tends to infiny